# Get canvas location (cx/cy) in d3.js after animation for future reference?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I access and store the canvas locations (cx/cy) of a D3 object, after an animation, so I can use it as a starting point for the next animation?

I have the following enter transition:

```
var enterTransition = enter.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .delay(function(d, i) { return i * delay; })
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return Math.random()*width; })
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return Math.random()*height; });
```

As a result I really don't know where my nodes ended up.

A node may have children and a "click" event as a result.  If the user clicks on the node, I want the new batch of nodes to start in the parent and randomize out from there.  I define my nodes ("bubbles") like so...

```
var bubbles = vis.insert("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "enter")
  .selectAll("g")
    .data(d.children)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return colors(i); })
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return d.cx0; })  // for illustration purposes
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return d.cy0; })  // for illustration purposes
    .attr("r", function(d, i) { return rScaled(d.duration); })
    .style("cursor", function(d) { return !d.children ? null : "pointer"; })
    .on("click", down);
```

My `d.cx0` and `d.cy0` represent the parent node's cx/cy.

How can I grab this information after the animation and hold it for reference?

Answer (score 1):

In the function you have for setting `"cx"` and `"cy"`:

```
.attr("cx", function(d, i) { 
  // In here, the "this" keyword refers to the svg circle. So:
  var parent = this.parentNode;// That's the parent you're interested in
  return d3.select(parent).attr('cx');
})
```

(Not being familiar enough with what you have and what you're trying to achieve, there may well be a more appropriate way to achieve this that doesn't rely on reading the parent's attributes, which is sort of expensive, I think).

Comment: I gave it a shot, but it does not appear cx/cy are being pulled correctly (bubbles still appear at 0,0).  Using the a debug tool (Firebug or Chrome) `this` is being reported as the `Window` each time.  Do I perhaps have a reference messed up somewhere?

Comment: Hmmmm. That's surprising that `this` is `Window`. Are you logging it from within the anonymous function being passed to `attr()`, just like I have it, or are you calling another function from within it and logging from the other function (which would lose the `this` context)? If that's not the issue, then maybe it doesn't work with svg the way it works with regular DOM elements. I'm not really sure.

Comment: I am still calling it from the anonymous function, using: `.attr("cx", function(d, i) { return d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("cx"); })`